# Running Kolmogorov-Smirnov test (scipy.stats.kstest)

Tags: python, r, matplotlib, scipy, gspread

I have created code that grabs data from a google api that I have created. I attempt to run the code however, I am having an issue with the estimate_cdf(). I am not sure what to put in the parenthesis, as I am not the most experienced in python. Any ideas? attached below

```
from scipy.stats import kstest
import numpy as np
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import  ServiceAccountCredentials


def estimate_cdf (col, bins=10):
    # 'col'
    # 'bins'
    hist, edges = np.histogram(col)
    csum = np.cumsum(hist)    
    return csum/csum[-1], edges

client = gspread.authorize(creds)

sheet = client.open("ramp").sheet1  # Open the spreadhseet

data = sheet.get_all_records()

row = sheet.row_values(3)  # Get a specific row


***estimate_cdf()***
(array([0.19444444, 0.27777778, 0.33333333, 0.38888889, 0.44444444, 0.52777778, 0.6111111, 0.69444444, 0.83333333, 1.]),
 array([-0.06, 0.0421, 0.1442, 0.2463, 0.3484, 0.4505, 0.5526, 0.6547, 0.7568, 0.8589, 0.961]))
col = sheet.col_values(3)  # Get a specific column print (col)

np.array(col).astype(np.float)
print(col)
    
cell = sheet.cell(1,2).value  # Get the value of a specific cell

cdf, values = estimate_cdf(col, bins=len(col))
teststat = kstest(values, cdf)
```

Comment: Pls be more specific about what `estimate_cdf()` should do. Then pass to it all needed arguments. Note that `bins` is not used.

Comment: im not sure how i would do that, could you give an example?

Comment: this code is supposed to run a ks test. The purpose of the estimate cdf is to determine the cumulative distribution of the data.

Comment: check out examples here: https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/100334/scipy.stats.kstest